# JAXB unmarshalling empty tags

Tags: binding, jaxb, unmarshalling, xjc

I'm stucked trying to unmarshalling an xml generated by a third party, wich didn't send me any documentation or contract.That's bad, so i cannot predict what could happen in the thirdparty xml. My business logic is that i have to send (marshal) an xml to the thirdparty, and to receive the same data. My current problem lies when i receive those data. The data is comming with empty tags, so after a research i designed a solution for those tags (in the xsd). Like above (using jaxb 2.0 standard impl.):

```
<xs:simpleType name="emptyIntegerAllowed">  
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:integer empty" />  
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="emptyLongAllowed">  
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:long empty" />  
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="emptyDecimalAllowed">  
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:double empty" />  
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="empty">  
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">  
     <xs:enumeration value="" />  
  </xs:restriction>  
</xs:simpleType>
```

And por example used that type like that:

```
<xs:element name="peso" type="emptyDecimalAllowed" minOccurs="0"/>
```

That approach really worked for integer and for long types, but now i'm getting a problem with the decimal types (when they're not empty). Unmarshalling '0,00' value produce the following stack:

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
     - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/joao/jboss-4.2.2.GA/serv/rio_branco/correio/postagem/retorno/testejoao.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1566; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: '0,00' is not a valid value of union type 'emptyDecimalAllowed'.]

In runtime (even debugging) i couldn't realize an cause to the problem, in my java code it even hit the javaTypeAdapter that i had created, following the xjb designed like above (jaxb extensions - xjc):

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"

           jaxb:version="2.0"> 
<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="PostagemCorreio.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

       <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='emptyDecimalAllowed']">
        <xjc:javaType name="net.riobranco.vendas.services.correio.EmptyDecimalAllowed"
                       adapter="net.riobranco.vendas.services.correio.DecimalAdapter" />
       </jaxb:bindings>

   </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Than my adapter is designed above:

```
public class DecimalAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, EmptyDecimalAllowed> {
  public EmptyDecimalAllowed unmarshal(String value) {
    value = value.replace(',', '.');
    return new EmptyDecimalAllowed(value);
  }

  public String marshal(EmptyDecimalAllowed value) {
    if (value == null) {
     return null;
    }
    return value.toString();
  }
}
```

And my binging java class:

```
public class EmptyDecimalAllowed extends BigDecimal {

  public EmptyDecimalAllowed(String value) {
    super(value);
  }

}
```

Thanks everybody for the attention in advance.

Comment: I would try this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237593/xml-schema-validation-different-separator-for-datatype-double

Comment: You `emptyXXXAllowed` types would be better mapped as `xs:string`, since both empty elements and commas are allowed in string types (and empty elements and digits with commas are not numbers). Then you can provide the conversion to decimal types in code, as you did in the adapter.

Comment: Using the tip provided by user3722530 i was able to fix the current stack, however the tip that was send by helderdarocha it's all true however i'd prefer to have a type binded to my code, i think that's turns the xsd more concise