# XSD validation for ANSI X3.9

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to create an XSD file for validation of the Decimal String (DS) as defined in DICOM by:

- http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_6.2.html#para_15754884-9ca2-4b12-9368-d66f32bc8ce1

This is basically an [`xsd:double`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#double) with a limitation of 16 bytes, and the special values `-Inf`, `+Inf` and `NaN` are not acceptable.

So far, I tried:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DecimalString">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
  <xsd:totalDigits value="16"/>
 </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

but this does not work, since it wont accept scientific notation ('E' or 'e' notation). I also tried:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DecimalString">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

But not only does it accept the `NaN`/`Inf` special values but it also does not allow for specifying a `totalDigits` value of 16.

How would one specify such validation rules in XSD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution may be:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DecimalString">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:pattern value="[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"/>
  <xsd:maxLength value="16" />
 </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Based from:

- [XML-schema/validation: different separator for datatype double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237593/xml-schema-validation-different-separator-for-datatype-double)
- [Java: how to parse double from regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681242/java-how-to-parse-double-from-regex)
- [XSD: how to restrict number of characters in string type attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966948/xsd-how-to-restrict-number-of-characters-in-string-type-attribute)